# Parsing Nested Arrays Data

Tags: javascript

How to parse the data of Nested JS Array to Objects? I've tried different approaches by using for loop and Dict datatype but it's not working.

Background :
I'm using chart.js library to show some data points in Radar Chart.Now i am trying to parse the nested arrays data and convert each array of module into single object and then pass it's data to visualization chart.

```
// Input--> 
JavaScript_Array=
[["Q1","Module1",9],["Q2","Module1",5],["Q3","Module1",8],
["Q1","Module2",5],["Q2","Module2",9],["Q3","Module2",1],
["Q1","Module3",2],["Q2","Module3",1],["Q3","Module3",3],
["Q1","Module4",3],["Q2","Module4",4],["Q3","Module4",2]]

//Expected Output

    Final_Array=[{label: "Module1",  data: [9,5,8],Questions:[Q1,Q2,Q3] },
                 {label: "Module2",  data: [5,9,1],Questions:[Q1,Q2,Q3]},
                 {label: "Module3",  data: [2,1,3],Questions:[Q1,Q2,Q3]},
                 {label: "Module4",  data: [3,4,2],Questions:[Q1,Q2,Q3]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `reduce` the array and group based on the `label`. Create an accumulator with each unique label as the key and the object you need in the output as value. If the label doesn't exist on the accumulator yet, add it. Then, update the respective keys of the object. Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) get the array of values from the grouped object:

```js
const input=[["Q1","Module1",9],["Q2","Module1",5],["Q3","Module1",8],["Q1","Module2",5],["Q2","Module2",9],["Q3","Module2",1],["Q1","Module3",2],["Q2","Module3",1],["Q3","Module3",3],["Q1","Module4",3],["Q2","Module4",4],["Q3","Module4",2]];

const merged = input.reduce((acc, [q, label, n]) => {
  acc[label] = acc[label] || { label, data: [], Questions: [] };
  acc[label].data.push(n);
  acc[label].Questions.push(q);
  return acc
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged)

console.log(output)
```

This is how the merged/ accumulator object looks like

```js
{
  "Module1": {
    label: "Module1",
    data: [9, 5, 8],
    Questions: ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3"]
  },
  "Module2": {
    ...
  }, 
  "Module3": {
    ...
  }
}
```